# CSS display a hidden drop-up menu on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a drop-up footer that is working great :

```js
$('#drop-up-open').click(function() {
  $('#drop-up #drop-upDashboard').slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 300);
  $(this).toggleClass('drop-upClose');
}); // end click
```

```css
#drop-up {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#drop-up-open {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#drop-up .drop-upClose {}

#drop-up #drop-upDashboard {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
#drop-up #drop-upDashboard{ 
display:block; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
    <header class="jumbotron panel-heading">

    <p class="text-center">
    
                Text getting covered by drop-up menu on mobile

    </p>

    <section>
                <a href="#"><button> Main button </button></a>
    </section>
    
    </header>

<div id="drop-up">
  <a href="#" id="drop-up-open">Open</a>

  <div id="drop-upDashboard">
    <p>It's now open!</p>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <section> <a href="#"><button>
                            
                            <p>Button 1</p>

                        </button></a> </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <section> <a href="#"><button>
                            
                            <p>Button 2</p>

                        </button></a> </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <section> <a href="#"><button>
                            
                            <p>Button 3</p>

                        </button></a> </section>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
        <section> <a href="#"><button>
                            
                            <p>Button 4</p>

                        </button></a> </section>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- row -->
  </div>
  <!-- dashboard -->
</div>
<!-- drop-up -->
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

When I click the id="drop-up" div, the menu opens from bottom to top and occupies a small portion of the bottom of the window on desktop view.

Now, what I want is that this menu which is at first hidden on desktop view, gets displayed on smaller devices (mobile+tablet) without having to click the id="drop-up" div. It would occupy the same portion of the bottom of the page on mobile+tablet (and the user would then need to scroll down to see the drop-up menu on smaller devices, which is not the case on desktop view).

Any suggestions/tips about the best method to achieve this ?

Comment: this is easily achieved with `@media` queries. There should be plenty of examples online

Comment: Thank you. I've just edited the CSS part. However, I have a size problem, as the buttons gets stacked on each other on mobile, and they dont get restricted at the bottom of the page as they should be but instead go beyond their supposed limit and display on top of the content above. Any clue on this ?

Comment: unsure what you mean, are they not supposed to stack? It looks fine to me, maybe edit your snippet a bit more to show the 'content' it's going above or w/e

Comment: I have a simple header above as edited. Indeed the buttons are supposed to stack on mobile, but they are not supposed to display on top of the header. I must have got something wrong.

Comment: Yes, that's because of `position absolute` Position absolute functions similarly to `fixed` but allows it to be positioned relative to a `display relative` element rather than the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the whole thing in a flex box, then have the body flex to fill up the rest of the space, thus putting your footer at the footer level. Also 'appears' to work when you go responsive.

HOWEVER, this feels quite hacky at the moment, as if you draw a border around the flex box container, it'll only fit at its original 100% level.

```js
$('#drop-up-open').click(function() {
  $('#drop-up #drop-upDashboard').slideToggle({
    direction: "up"
  }, 300);
  $(this).toggleClass('drop-upClose');
}); // end click
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
#drop-up-open {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#drop-up .drop-upClose {}

#drop-up #drop-upDashboard {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  #drop-up #drop-upDashboard{ 
  display:block; }

  html, body {
    height: auto !important;
  }

}


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <!-- Jumbotron Header -->
    <header class="jumbotron panel-heading" style="background-color: yellow; opacity: 0.7">

      <p class="text-center">

                  Text getting covered by drop-up menu on mobile

      </p>

      <section>
                  <a href="#"><button> Main button </button></a>
      </section>

    </header>
    
    <div class="body" style="background-color: orange; opacity: 0.3">
      a body
    </div>

  <div id="drop-up" style="background-color: lightblue; opacity: 0.7">
    <a href="#" id="drop-up-open">Open</a>

    <div id="drop-upDashboard">
      <p>It's now open!</p>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <section> <a href="#"><button>

                              <p>Button 1</p>

                          </button></a> </section>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <section> <a href="#"><button>

                              <p>Button 2</p>

                          </button></a> </section>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <section> <a href="#"><button>

                              <p>Button 3</p>

                          </button></a> </section>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <section> <a href="#"><button>

                              <p>Button 4</p>

                          </button></a> </section>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- dashboard -->
  </div>
  <!-- drop-up -->
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: I agree this is pretty hacky. Maybe the best way would be to say that if responsive, then display "drop-up" with position: relative rather than absolute.
Is there a media query for this ?

Comment: you could just add a `mobile` class tag and then try `display: relative !important` and see if it works

Comment: I've also made some edits, so I think it should be better now, take a look

Comment: @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #drop-up #drop-upDashboard{ 
  display:block; }
  #drop-up { 
  position:relative; }
}
It's all good, thanks !